# Not able to setup multiple series Flot graph properly

Tags: jquery, flot

I am not able to get this jquery FLOT graph to work properly with the below dataset. Don't know what I am doing wrong. The JSON data set and the javascript to make it work is written below. Can anyone help me get this to work. Thank you in advance.

This is the data set I want to use.

```
var data = [
{
    "label": "Uncloaked",
    "data": [
            [10:22, 0]
                ,[10:14, 0]
                ,[09:30, 1]
                ,[09:29, 1]
                ,[09:27, 1]
                ,[09:28, 2]
                ,[09:26, 1]
                ,[09:18, 0]
                ,[09:16, 1]
                ,[09:15, 2]
                ,[09:11, 1]
                ,[09:10, 0]
                ,[09:09, 2]
                ,[09:08, 3]
                ,[09:07, 1]
                ,[09:06, 3]
                ,[09:05, 4]
                ,[09:04, 1]
                ,[09:03, 5]
                ,[09:02, 7]
                ,[09:01, 6]
                ,[09:00, 9]
                ,[08:59, 6]
                ,[08:58, 8]
                ,[08:57, 6]
                ,[08:56, 4]
                ,[08:55, 6]
                ,[08:54, 9]
                ,[08:53, 3]
                ,[08:52, 3]
                ,[08:51, 4]
                ,[08:50, 3]
                ,[08:49, 1]
                ,[08:48, 1]
                ,[08:47, 5]
                ,[08:46, 3]
                ,[08:45, 1]
                ,[08:44, 1]
                ,[08:43, 2]
                ,[08:42, 2]
                ,[08:41, 6]
                ,[08:40, 2]
                ,[08:39, 3]
                ,[08:38, 2]
                ,[08:37, 3]
                ,[08:36, 5]
                ,[08:35, 1]
                ,[08:34, 2]
                ,[08:33, 7]
                ,[08:32, 3]
                ,[08:31, 4]
                ,[08:30, 2]
                ,[08:29, 1]
                ,[08:28, 3]
                ,[08:27, 4]
                ,[08:26, 2]
                ,[08:25, 7]
                ,[08:24, 5]
                ,[08:23, 4]
                ,[08:22, 7]
                ,[08:21, 5]
                ,[08:20, 4]
            ]
},
{
    "label": "Cloaked",
    "data": [
            [10:22, 1]
                ,[10:14, 1]
                ,[09:30, 0]
                ,[09:29, 1]
                ,[09:27, 1]
                ,[09:28, 0]
                ,[09:26, 0]
                ,[09:18, 1]
                ,[09:16, 0]
                ,[09:15, 0]
                ,[09:11, 0]
                ,[09:10, 2]
                ,[09:09, 0]
                ,[09:08, 0]
                ,[09:07, 0]
                ,[09:06, 4]
                ,[09:05, 1]
                ,[09:04, 2]
                ,[09:03, 5]
                ,[09:02, 4]
                ,[09:01, 2]
                ,[09:00, 2]
                ,[08:59, 2]
                ,[08:58, 1]
                ,[08:57, 3]
                ,[08:56, 3]
                ,[08:55, 2]
                ,[08:54, 1]
                ,[08:53, 2]
                ,[08:52, 2]
                ,[08:51, 0]
                ,[08:50, 4]
                ,[08:49, 2]
                ,[08:48, 1]
                ,[08:47, 0]
                ,[08:46, 2]
                ,[08:45, 1]
                ,[08:44, 1]
                ,[08:43, 1]
                ,[08:42, 2]
                ,[08:41, 2]
                ,[08:40, 2]
                ,[08:39, 4]
                ,[08:38, 2]
                ,[08:37, 1]
                ,[08:36, 0]
                ,[08:35, 2]
                ,[08:34, 2]
                ,[08:33, 1]
                ,[08:32, 2]
                ,[08:31, 2]
                ,[08:30, 1]
                ,[08:29, 3]
                ,[08:28, 5]
                ,[08:27, 5]
                ,[08:26, 0]
                ,[08:25, 1]
                ,[08:24, 2]
                ,[08:23, 1]
                ,[08:22, 1]
                ,[08:21, 0]
                ,[08:20, 1]
            ]
}
]
```

Below is my JS code.

```
$.plot("#site_statistics", data, {
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: true,
            lineWidth: 2,
            fill: true,
            fillColor: {
                colors: [{
                        opacity: 0.05
                    }, {
                        opacity: 0.01
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        points: {
            show: true
        },
        shadowSize: 2
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: true,
        tickColor: "#eee",
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    colors: ["#d12610", "#37b7f3", "#52e136"],
    xaxis: {
        mode: "categories",
        tickLength: 0
    }
});
```

I don't know why it is not working. I have been scratching my head to make this work. Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: Also, is that how your data appears in the actual script?  As written above, the first value in each pair, i.e. 10:22, is invalid syntax for JavaScript.

Comment: @DNS Thanks for asking. But I figured out the issue. It's a great tool. Keep up the good work! :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:
$.plot($(

note the $ and parenthesis

and remember to add the extra closing parenthesis